# Wix Check if Application Initialization is installed on 2008R2

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I need to check if Application Initialization is installed on a 2008R2 Server.

The app is not installed as a feature, it is an IIS Module that I downloaded from the following [link](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization).

The problem I'm having is where does the folders actually get placed to be able to perform a search in my WiX project to see if they exist or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*TLDR:*

Look for the `Version` value in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\Application Initilaization`. Current version is **7.1.1636.0**.

*Full answer:*

Since this is a MSI installation package, you can open it using Orca and search for any registry key being created.

Then in Orca, you open the Registry table and find the 
row with `Registry=reg8BD5741527F144C70BDB7B0134BC7B84`. In it, you will find the `Key` where the value will be created, the `Name` of it and the `Value`.

This way, you  can easily perform a registry search and evaluate if the module is installed.

**EDIT**

To perform a search during launch and verify if the module is installed, add the following code:

```
<Property Id="MODULEINSTALLED">
    <RegistrySearch Id="IsModuleInstalled"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\Application Initilaization"
             Name="Version"
                    Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

Then use the property in a condition:

```
<Condition Message="This application requires Application Initialization module. Please install the Application Initialization module then run this installer again.">
    <![CDATA[Installed OR MODULEINSTALLED]]>
</Condition>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, I think I should be okay for this, essentially I just need to check whereever the file is there or not, as I assume if it was not installed that folder directory would not exist?

Comment: You should use a `RegistrySearch` to verify if the module is installed. I expanded the answer to cover this.